# Increasing PHP Variable onSroll without reloading the page

Tags: php, jquery, facebook-graph-api

Ok,

I've seen a couple of solutions out there but I am looking for the most lightweight version to accomplish this following:

```
<?php
$number = 20;
$counter = 0; 
$i = 1;
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
  foreach($friends['data'] as $friend) 
  {
    if ($counter++ == $number) { 
        break;
    }
    echo '<li id="'.$i++.'"><img src="http://graph.facebook.com/'.$friend['id'].'/picture"/>'.$friend['name'].'</li>';
  }

 ?>
```

I want to be able to increase $number = 20 when the user scrolls past a speecific div.

So for instance I know I can use jQuery for the scrolling mechanism:

```
<script>
$('#20').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    if (direction === 'down') {

                 "Increase php variable to 40"

    };

});

 </script>
```

If you guys can provide any knowledge it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP runs server sided, meaning that the **whole** page gets computed before outputting. What you are doing is not possible the way you are approaching it.

There are two approaches that will work in this situation:

1. Output all the information to begin with, but hide it and when the user scrolls to whatever point show it programatically with Javascript
2. Use AJAX to do dynamic page generation. 
   AJAX allows you to make requests to the server from Javascript to request remote content. For example, you could grab the content of myFile.php?count=123 and output the result in a div.

   See http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_example.asp for an example on how to use AJAX.